# my function doesn't return my expected output

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am a beginner in c. I write a function to return an array containing all elements common to two given arrays containing distinct positive integers.

Examples:

| input | return |
| --- | --- |
| 1832 , 4261 | 12 |
| 18326 , 261 | 261 |
| 1379 , 7193 | 1379 |
| 12 , 34 | empty array(EA) |
| EA , 123 | EA |
| 12 , EA | EA |
| 12 , null | null |
| null , EA | null |
| null , null | null |

I write the following code but when I build it. this latter gave me an unwanted output. Can anyone help me??

```
int *f(int first[], int second[], int first_len, int second_len)
{
    if (first == NULL || second == NULL) return NULL;
    if (first_len == 0 || second_len == 0) return malloc(0);
    int min = (first_len < second_len) ? first_len : second_len;
 int *a, *b;
 if (min == first_len)
    {
        a = first;
        b = second;
    }
 else
 {
        a = second;
        b = first;
 }
    int *c = malloc(min);
    int k = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i <(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)); i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(b)/sizeof(*b)) ; j++)
     {
       if (a[i] == b[j])
        {
            c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
        }
     }
 }

int *retArray = malloc(k * (sizeof(retArray)/sizeof(*retArray)));
     if (retArray == NULL)
        {
             return NULL;
        }
int result_len = sizeof(retArray)/sizeof(*retArray);
 for (int t = 0; t < result_len; t++)
 {
            retArray[t] = c[t];
 }
     return retArray;
}
int main()
{
    int first[] = {1,3,8,9};
    int second[] = {NULL};
    int first_len = sizeof(first)/sizeof(*first);
    int second_len = sizeof(second)/sizeof(*second);
    int *comm = f(first,second,first_len,second_len);

    if (comm == NULL)
    {
        printf("null\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int result_len = sizeof(comm)/sizeof(*comm);
    for (int i = 0; i < result_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", comm[i]);
    }

    free(comm); // free the storage returned by f()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok. I understand. Can I change result_len as the argument parameter of the "f" function ?

Comment: And why the return of the function doesn't print null

Comment: Could you expand on "gave me an unwanted output"? Anyone trying to see the error is shooting in the dark at the moment.